# JQuery Mobile and Mediaelements.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mediaelement.js

Is there a compatibility problem with JQuery Mobile and mediaelements? Whenever I try to make a page with the player, its buttons are blackened out.

Try this html page: http://mt.ccnmtl.columbia.edu/majmin_mbl/m/test.html

As you can see, the buttons are black. If I take away the jquery mobile code, it works fine though.

How do I fix this?

Comment: its actually getting `class="ui-btn-hidden"` on play and volume button If you can provide the code it would be easy to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a styling issue, but since medieelement renders the elements after you initiate it... the data-role attribute is lost.  So you actually need to specifically apply it after you initiate the mediaelement like this.

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({});
$('button').attr("data-role","none");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jquery mobile is trying to style the controls. Add the data-role="none" to any control you don't want jquery mobile to style.